# Is it possible to retrieve SSH keys on an installation where the /home corrupted?

Tags: ssh

I used to work in another company with part of my duty to maintain some codes on a Ubuntu platform. Therefore, I used to own a set of SSH keys on that old HDD. Later (some years ago) where my /home was mounted on a spreaded LVM made by 2 1TB disk corrupted. But then I do not need to do any coding, as I left that company.

Now I work in another company, and joined GitLab.com again. Shall I try to recover my old key, which may stored somewhere outside /home, or shall I create a new set of SSH keys and replace all my presents on net?

Answer (score 1):

As a general rule of security, if you have lost control of your keys, then you need to make new keys and revoke the old ones.

Think about it this way:  If you lost the keys to your house, would the locksmith try to recover your keys or install a new lock?

Comment: But then that means you have to surrender all accounts you created with that sets of key in GitHub, Launchpad, etc.

Comment: Using the same key everywhere is like using the same password everywhere.  Don't do it mmmmk? :-p

Answer (score 0):

Sounds silly, but when I tried to build a VM of Ubuntu 19.04, I found I can import SSH keys from either GitHub or Launchpad.net, and then I found my keys stored in Launchpad.net ......

Sometimes, you just need to trust luck.